# Overwrite every file from a folder ( in Windows )

Tags: ms-dos

Is there any chance to overwrite all the files that are in a folder?

Eg. In folder d:/data I have different files with different extensions ( .mp3, .txt etc )

What I am trying is to do is to overwrite their contents with empty content. So the titles will remain intact but without content.

Is it possible with a MS Dos command?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Are you only working with word documents. Not sure how you play on 'overwriting' the content of a .mp3 file.

Comment: are you looking to destroy the contents permanently?  There are programs called "file shredders" that will write over a files contents  with random data to make them unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b "d:\ff\"') do copy /y NUL d:\ff\%f
```

where you will replace d:\ff\ with the directory that you need to work on.

Answer (score 0):

A(nother) possibility:

`for /r %F in (*) do @(copy /y nul %F) > nul`

This will silently overwrite all files in the current folder with NULL, leaving 0-byte files.

Be careful. :)